# Writte text file with message to FTP

Tags: php, ftp

I want to create a folder and create a file with a given message inside that folder on a FTP server.
Following is my attempt:

```
<?php

$dirname = "files/";
$dir = $_GET["name"];
$dirname .= $dir;
$filepath = $dirname."/message.txt";
$txt = $_GET["message"];

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect("example.com");

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, "login", "password");

// try to create the directory and file
if (ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $dirname)) {
 echo "successfully created $dirname\n";
 $myfile = fopen('php://temp', 'r+') or die("Unable to open file!");
 fwrite($myfile, $txt);
 rewind($myfile);
 ftp_fput($conn_id, $filepath, $myfile, FTP_ASCII);

} else {
 echo "There was a problem while creating $dirname\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

This creates the folder with the given name and also puts a message.txt file inside that folder but the file is always empty. How can I add my message to the file?

Comment: Try `a+` or `w+` instead of `r+`. Also, try to remove the dot in `$dirname .= $dir;` => `$dirname = $dir;`

Comment: Plus, where are your GETs coming from?

Comment: I have not done what you are doing, but I doubt it would would work without rewinding the file pointer. Between `fwrite` and `ftp_fput` add `rewind($myfile);`

Comment: GETs are coming from the URL when the PHP gets called. I changed it to 'w+' and also added the rewind function but I still get an empty message.txt

Comment: This is how I call it `up.php?name=foldername&message=hello`. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: You do not need to use `w+`. Every example I've seen with temp files is using `r+`. Both open the file for reading and writing. Using w tries to create a new file. That may be your problem. You may have failed to open the file properly and then the rewind (which I have checked and found is required) won't work.

Comment: code is updated to `r+` and `rewind`. I still get an empty message.txt file

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: I just found the problem. Until now I have always tried to check my message.txt file by just clicking "view/edit" in filezilla. Just now I decided to download it and my message is inside it. I feel so stupid. Thanks for your help anyways @kainaw

Comment: I tested this on my computer. It worked. The file on the FTP server received the content I sent to it. Please check permissions on the FTP server if you are not getting any PHP errors or warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be most comfortable with using [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) to write to a local file. My solution would look like this.

```
<?php

$dirname = "files/";
$dir = $_GET["name"];
$dirname .= $dir;
$filepath = $dirname."/message.txt";
$txt = $_GET["message"];

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect("example.com");

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, "login", "password");

// try to create the directory and file
if (ftp_mkdir($conn_id, $dirname)) {
echo "successfully created $dirname\n";
$myfile = fopen('php://temp', 'r+') or die("Unable to open file!");

// Here is the good stuff with shell_exec.
$myfilelocation = '~/myfile.txt';
shell_exec( "cat $txt >> $myfilelocation" );

ftp_fput($conn_id, $filepath, $myfile, FTP_ASCII);

} else {
echo "There was a problem while creating $dirname\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Comment: I still get an empty message.txt file in the directory. Am I doing something wrong with calling it like `up.php?name=foldername&message=hello`?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be opening the file in read mode `('php://temp', 'r+')`

try fopen `('php://temp', 'w +')`